# unable to hide the div on selection of dropdown in php

Tags: php

Hi i have a dropdown based on the dropdown selection div value should be changed.By default it is displaying no and showing the div, If i select yes displaying a text box and the other div is not hiding.

```
<div class="col-sm-12"> 
                                        <select name="full_part_time" id="full_part_time" onchange="if (this.value=='yes'){this.form['full_part_time_details'].style.visibility='visible'}else {this.form['full_part_time_details'].style.visibility='hidden'};">
                                            <option value="no" <?php echo ($oppointArr['full_part_time'] == 'no')?'selected':''?>>no</option>
                                            <option value="yes" <?php echo ($oppointArr['full_part_time'] == 'yes')?'selected':''?>>yes</option>                                                
                                        </select>
                                        <?php 
                                            $visibleText = 'style="visibility:hidden;"';
                                            if($oppointArr['full_part_time'] == "yes"){
                                                $visibleText = 'style="visibility:visible;"';
                                            }
                                        ?>
                                        <input type="text" id="full_part_time_details"  <?php echo $visibleText;?> value="After my retirement, I am not in full or part time employment or Service not engaged in any trade or business or profession till today. " readonly/>
                                        <?php //print_r($oppointArr); ?>                                            
                                        
                                        <div class="droddownsselection">
                                            <p>Service Candidates shall upload following documents along with service Affidavit. </p>
                                            <ul style="list-style:none;">
                                                <li>1. Retirement Order / Service Certificate.</li>
                                                <li>2. Permission Letter from Employer</li>
                                                <li>3. Proof of working during study period of LAW</li>
                                                <li>4. Law T.C.</li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                        
                                    </div>
```

Comment: PHP is rendered on the server and knows nothing about anything you do on the client (unless you tell it (AJAX)). You'd need to submit the form for PHP to get the new value. Not PHP related, you'd need to solve this using Javascript (if you don't want to submit the form)

Comment: @brombeer display and hide functionality is working for the condition yes if i select yes its working fine but not for the condition no